# Page with GridView ASP.NET not display in browser

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I try to bind data from code behind into a GridView. I don't know what's wrong cause there is no error from debug, but when I try to display the page in browser it doesn't display (the hole page won't come up).

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="productCart" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="There is nothing in your shopping cart." GridLines="None" Width="100%" CellPadding="5" ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="ProductId">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#F36EA7" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="#6C6B66" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" Columns="5" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' style="font-size:12px;"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs:

```
public partial class Cart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    UserSingleton activeUser = UserSingleton.Instance;
    List<CartItem_Test> CartItems = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = Access.GetInfo("CartPerUserID", "*", "UserID=" + activeUser.get_user().ID);
    if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        CartItems = new List<CartItem_Test>(dataTable.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            CartItem_Test cartItem = new CartItem_Test(row);
            CartItems.Add(cartItem);
        }
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        productCart.DataSource = CartItems;
        productCart.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Several things to check. Look for a client side JavaScript error. Also try setting a breakpoint at the first line of your `Page_Load` function and stepping through the code to verify it flows like you expect it to and that you're actually retrieving data from the database.

Comment: I tried to set a breakpoint and checked Page_Load function, it works perfectly. It's so strange. I also tried to display the page without the GridView and it worked just fine. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: When you say the "whole page won't come up", what does the HTML look like? Please update your question to include it.

Comment: A blank page with this message : "Are you having problems logging? Make sure you have entered the correct URL, or try again later"

Comment: When you set the breakpoint and stepped through the code, did you make it all the way to the end of the page_load function? Do you have any code that might perform a redirect?

Comment: Yes, did it all the way to the end of page_load function and it returned to the MasterPage.

Comment: Watch the network traffic in the browser, it looks like you're getting redirected at some point. The event may be in your page, in your master page, a user control, or possibly even something in your `global.asax`. You'll have to look through your application and see what some reasons you might end up on that page are.

Comment: I still don't get the problem. As long as I don't add <asp:GridView>....</asp:GridView> the page displays perfectly in browser so I don't think the problem is in the master page or in the page itself. Only when I add GridView my browser don't recognize this page as all.

Comment: Browsers do not "recognize pages". They display HTML, styled with CSS. You have to look at the HTML being sent down to the client, and you have to figure out at what address it's coming from. That means you need to learn to use your browser's debugging tools.